# How to match the resulting "map" with the given "color_map"?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, vision

I have a RGB image called imrgb, the size of which is 320*512*3 double.And I 
also have the color_map = 64*3 double. I use the following code:

```
[X, map] = rgb2ind(imrgb, 256)
```

the resulting X= 320*512 uint8, and the resulting map = 65*3 double.
The resulting "map" is totally different from the given "color_map".
How to fix this problem?

The first few rows of "map" looks like this:

```
    0      0        0
    0      0.125    1
    0.56   1        0.439
    1      0.125    0
    0.188   1       0.812
    1       0.749   0
    0       0.7490  1
    0.5019  0       0
    0.7490  1       0.25098
```

The first few rows of given "color_map" looks like this:

```
0   0   0.5625
0   0   0.6250
0   0   0.6875
0   0   0.7500
0   0   0.8125
0   0   0.8750
0   0   0.9375
0   0       1
0   0.0625  1
```

Comment: Using `rgb2ind` performs a colour quantization of your image if you don't specify an input colour map and the `map` output provides a colour map that segments the colours using that quantization.  It **does not** have to correspond to a custom colour map that was provided by you **unless** you provide this colour map as input into `rgb2ind`.  It's a bit unclear on what you're doing here.  Can you please give some further insight as to the purpose of matching the colour maps?  What is your overall goal here?

Comment: @rayryeng, I want to get X to do further image processing work. The "color_map" and " imrgb" are given, I just want to use what I have now to get the exactly two dimensional X to represent my image. As you said, does that mean I should feed the given  "color_map" together with the given "imrgb" into the equation?

Comment: @rayryeng, should I do like this: [X, color_map] = rgb2ind(imrgb, 256)? Or there is still something I do not know.

Comment: Try doing `[X, map] = rgb2ind(imrgb, color_map);`.

Comment: @rayryeng, Ok I try now

Comment: Cool :)  Can I write an answer and you can accept it?

Comment: @rayryeng, I just want to ask you to write an answer so that I can vote! Do it,please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`rgb2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2ind.html) performs a colour quantization (the default is uniform quantization directly in RGB space and we also apply [dithering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dither) to the image) of your image to a certain number of colours (in your case, 256) if you don't specify an input colour map. The `map` output provides a colour map that best segments the colours using that quantization for your image `imrgb`. The variable `X` gives you **indices** of where each pixel maps to in the colour map from the `map` variable.  This is actually a lookup table of colours.

This `map` variable tells us which colour from the lookup table that the pixel should be visualized as.  For example, the above call in your post will produce an indexed image `X` that has indices from 1 to 256 and `map` will contain 256 rows where each column is a proportion of red (first column), green (second column) and blue (third column).  The proportions are between `[0-1]`.  Also, each row is a unique colour.  Therefore, if an index found in the image was 5, we'd look up the fifth row of this colour map and that is the colour that would be representative of that pixel.

Therefore, calling `rgb2ind` in your current way **does not** correspond to a custom colour map that was provided by you unless you provide this colour map as input into `rgb2ind`.  As such, if you want to obtain an indexed image using a custom colour map provided by you, use this colour map as input into `rgb2ind` so that the indexed image is with respect to this new colour map.

In that case, you simply need to do:

```
[X, map] = rgb2ind(imrgb, colour_map);
```